# Unable to update wordpress due to database error unknown column

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I get this error in my wordpress error log

WordPress database error Unknown column 'tickbox_auto' in 'where clause' for query SELECT * FROM `wpdx_payment_discount` WHERE status = 1 AND tickbox_auto = 1 AND tickbox = 1 AND tickbox_value <= '27.990000' ORDER by tickbox_value DESC made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), do_action('template_redirect'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, ads_theme_redirect, apply_filters('ads_plugin_template'), WP_Hook->apply_filters, ads_cart_template, load_template, require_once('/plugins/alids/template/cart/index.php'), ads\cart\adsCheckout->__construct, ads\cart\adsCheckout->getFieldArgs, ads\cart\adsCheckout->getBasketOrders, ads\adsBasket->getBasketOrdersFull, ads\adsBasket->applyDiscountFull, ads\adsDiscount->findTickCode

I couldn't find way to fix it.

Comment: Believe the message

Answer (score 0):

In the table `wpdx_payment_discount` there is no column named `tickbox_auto` so the query failed. Do you have updated somenthing recently? Is the plugin/theme installed correctly? You can avoid the error adding the column using a backup for example.

Comment: The plugin installed correctly, everything works fine accept this error, is there any tutorial on how to adding the column?

Comment: According to your query, the column type seems integer so you can add one using this SQL: ```ALTER TABLE wpdx_payment_discount ADD tickbox_auto INT NOT NULL DEFAULT(0);```

Comment: added but nothing happen

Comment: it gave me the same error, i'm not sure why

Comment: Execute manually the query on DB and see what happens. Take further investigation.